Upload multiple images in Django
I want to upload multiple images but it can’t upload multiple images at the same time.
Please help me fix them.
I have two models, one with Chapter and ChapterImage. I want to include all fields in the serializer and the related field.
models.py
from django.db import models
import uuid
from manga.models import *
# Create your models here.
import os
class Chapter(models.Model):
    # ... other fields ...
    images = models.ManyToManyField('ChapterImage')
class ChapterImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='chapter_images/')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.page)
    def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return os.path.join('chapters', filename)
class Chapter(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,  unique=True,
                           primary_key=True, editable=False)
    manga = models.ForeignKey(Manga, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)



class ChapterImage(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,  unique=True,
                           primary_key=True, editable=False)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(
        null=True, blank=True, default='/chapters/default.png', upload_to=get_file_path)
    page = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.page)

serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Chapter, ChapterImage


class ChapterImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChapterImage
        fields = ['image']

class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ChapterImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ['title', 'images']

class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = '__all__'


class ChapterDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chapterImages = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_chapterImages(self, obj):
        images = obj.chapterimage_set.all()
        serializer = ChapterImageSerializer(images, many=True)
        return serializer.data

Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from chapter.models import Chapter
from chapter.serializers import ChapterDetailSerializer, ChapterSerializer

from rest_framework import status

# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET'])
def getChapter(request, pk):
    try:
        chapter = Chapter.objects.get(_id=pk)
        chapter.views += 1
        chapter.save()

        serializer = ChapterDetailSerializer(chapter, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'details': f"{e}"}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


@api_view(['GET'])
def getChaptersByManga(request, pk):
    try:
        chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(manga__pk=pk)
        serializer = ChapterSerializer(chapters, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'details': f"{e}"}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    
class ChapterCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ChapterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': 'Chapter created successfully'})
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

I try upload multi-images but I can't do it. Please tell me, how do I solve it?
